# How to manipulate sequences of inequalities?

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, inequalities, algebra

I am trying to write some symbolic inequality proofs in Mathematica. What would be a clean way to make the inference that `a >= b` and `b > c` implies 
`a > c`? Or alternatively, given an inequality `b > c`, how I could apply a function to the left hand side only performing the transformation `f[b] = a`? I would be able to code it, but it feels kind of clumsy, I would like to do something simple as 'ApplySides', but for one side of the inequality only. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[a >= b && b > c, b, Reals]
```

> a > c && c < b <= a

Answer (score 0):

So far I have come up with this solution:

```
ApplyLeft[f_, rel_] := ReplacePart[rel, 1 -> f[rel[[1]]]]
ApplyRight[f_, rel_] := ReplacePart[rel, 2 -> f[rel[[2]]]]
```